# Syntax error in query but query is correct

Tags: c#, mysql

I wrote a general method to search if a value exists in a specific table, the method is really simple:

```
public bool CheckRecordExist(int id, string tableName, string column)
{
    string connection = string.Format("Server=localhost; database={0}; UID=root; password=root; SslMode=none; CharSet=utf8;", "myDb");
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);

    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + column " = @" + column;
    MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column, id);

   return Convert.ToBoolean(MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Suppose I want check if the record with id `2538782` exist on the table match, I do:

```
CheckRecordExist(2538782, "match", "id");
```

so the `query` variable will be:

```
SELECT * FROM match WHERE id = @id
```

if I run this in `PhpMyAdmin`, replacing the `id` with the value, I'll get the correct response, but inside my app I'll get:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match WHERE id = 2538782' at line 1'

what is wrong?

Comment: WARNING: SQL INJECTION RISK!!!

Comment: @rory.ap I think that is true of nearly all Stack Overflow SQL questions.

Comment: @rory.ap I run this locally on my machine, this app will never pushed online

Comment: @cojac, It doesn't matter if it's online, you can SQL injection yourself. Not all SQL injection problems are due to malicious web users.

Comment: @cojac -- That matters not.  Why would you code it the sub-optimal way when it's so straightforward to use query params?

Comment: @rory.ap, It's not possible to use query parameters for table names or column names.

Comment: Also what you have posted wouldn't even compile, this is why we usually use `string.Format` or string interpolation to build short strings like this.

Comment: I see a missing string concatenation: `WHERE " + column " = @" + column`. The `+` is missing after the first column reference.

Comment: @rory.ap I know, but please don't go off topic, my question is not about security

Comment: @cojac -- It's like if I said "WARNING: EXPLOSION RISK!!!" to a guy who was holding a lit match and a bottle of gasoline asking about why he can't seem to fit the match into the bottle.  It doens't matter what the topic is: people could come across this question on this public site, and they should be made well aware that there is a major risk in the code you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

`MATCH` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

You can use reserved words as identifiers only if you enclose them in delimiters. MySQL's default delimiter for identifiers is the back-tick.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Thank you Bill, this was the problem that afflicted me for hours, I'm grateful. Wish you a good day :)